# Why does rails redirect to the show action after creating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

New web developer here, and I think I may be missing some very fundamental knowledge.
Given the code

```
def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        if @post.save
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render "new"
        end
end
```

why does the view templates redirect to the **def show** action? If I do not define a **def show** and its corresponding views, rails will throw me an error.

I am just not understanding why even though the code is **redirect_to @post** after I save a post, it appears to be redirecting to the show page after creating a post. Is this just one of those rails thing that I should just take it as it is or am I missing some fundamental HTML protocol knowledge (which I honestly don't know a lot about)?

Edit: To further clarify my question, I see that **@post** is already defined in the **create** method and is defined as **Post.new(post_params).** when I **redirect_to @post**, wouldn't it simply call that line again?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Lets take a look at your code

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

> why does the view templates redirect to the def show action? If I do not define a def show and its corresponding views, rails will throw me an error.

In `create` action you are creating a new record, so if you look at this part of the code

```
if @post.save
  redirect_to @post
```

When `@post` is successfully saved, we are redirecting it to show action by writing `redirect_to @post`, the actual route for `show` action would be `post_path(@post)` so you can also write `redirect_to post_path(@post)` but even if you simply pass object with `redirect_to` rails will redirect it to the show action. Now going to the `else` part

```
else
  render "new"
```

If the `@post` object is not saved in the database(due to validation), we want to reload the form, so in the above code `render` is just rendering the view of `new` action and not calling the `new` action, only the view is rendered because `new.html.erb` contains the form.

Hope this helped!

Comment: thanks for the explanation! correct me if I am wrong, but does this mean redirect_to will always return to the show action? can I redirect_to something else?

Comment: Yes definitely, try `redirect_to "http://google.com"` instead and it will redirect to `google`, you can pass any `url` with redirect

Comment: I have exactly the same code as the OP but my `if` block is empty and it still keeps redirecting me to the create page, why would that be?